# What STL ports support usage of custom/smart pointers in custom allocators?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, stl

I'd like to persist collection with data (unordered_map for instance) in memory mapped file, so I need something like offset kind of pointer to deal with (collection can be mapped to any random address later so I need offset from the beginning of mapped region)). The goal is to create some big dictionary the way I don't have to initialize it every time to use it effective way (just attaching/mapping only to any available mem location on app startup).
When I try to implement it in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 I receive compilation errors showing collections (vector for instance) use raw pointers internally instead of my class to represent offset pointers.
I know boost/interprocess has own specialized/custom collections to persist data in shared memory (or memory mapped file), but I need data persistence way that can work with any STL container.

The question is like in title:
Does anybody know any STL implementation supporting custom smart pointer on custom allocators?

Maybe somebody did something like this already with success. I'm not sure definition of offset smart pointer is sufficient in such case only.

**Update 1**:
Below are definitions of the allocator and offset pointer I have at the moment...

Allocator:

```
    #include <memory>
    #include "esoft_offset_pointer.hpp"

    namespace esoft::mem_map_file_allocator
    {
        template<typename T> 
        class mmf_allocator
        {
        public:
            using value_type = T;
            using size_type = size_t;

            using pointer = mmf_offset_pointer<T>;
            using const_pointer = mmf_offset_pointer<const T>; //  T*;
            //using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;

            // rebind allocator to type U
            template <typename U>
            struct rebind {
                typedef mmf_allocator<U> other;
            };

            // constructors and destructor
            mmf_allocator() noexcept {};
            mmf_allocator(const mmf_allocator&) noexcept {};

            template <typename U>
            mmf_allocator(const mmf_allocator<U>&) noexcept {};

            ~mmf_allocator() {};

            pointer allocate(size_type num, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
            {
                return reinterpret_cast<pointer>(new char[num * sizeof(T)]);
            }

            // deallocate storage p of deleted elements
            void deallocate(pointer p, size_type num)
            {
                delete[] reinterpret_cast<T*>(p);
            }

            //// initialize elements of allocated storage p with values args
            //template <typename U, typename... Args>
            //void construct(U* p, Args&&... args)
            //{

            //}

            //// delete elements of initialized storage p
            //template <typename U>
            //void destroy(U* p)
            //{

            //}
        };
    }
```

Offset pointer:

```
namespace esoft::mem_map_file_allocator
{
    template<typename T>
    class mmf_offset_pointer
    {
    public:
        operator T*();
        T& operator ++();
        //friend size_t operator -(const mmf_offset_pointer<T> p1, const mmf_offset_pointer<T> p2);
    };
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include "esoft_allocator.hpp"

using namespace std;
namespace ea = esoft::mem_map_file_allocator;
using vec_offset_alloc = ea::mmf_allocator<int>;

int main()
{
    vector<int, vec_offset_alloc> vec;

    for (int pos = 10; pos < 20; ++pos)
    {
        vec.push_back(pos);
    }

    int k = vec[4];
    return 0;
}
```

I don't write body of methods yet. My goal is, first of all, to find the way (in reality set of methods and operators) to declare allocator and offset pointer the way it can be accepted by std::vector for instance.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not in the implementation of the standard library, but in the code for the custom allocator. But since that code isn't shown, it's impossible to give any sensible advice.

Comment: Hello Pete, thanks for so fast response. I will upload custom allocator on Monday when I'm back in the office. At the moment I can say only the allocator has allocate/deallocate methods and definition for offset pointer usage (something like "using pointer = my_offset_pointer<T>;"). Smart pointer has a few operators overloaded also just to make things working and compile - but maybe its definition is just incomplete (some missing operators for instance). Probably to make it working with address offsets some stuff to support iterators (operators?) is necessary also.

Comment: Hello Pete, I added what I have at the moment to main part of the question under "Update 1" section...